# How to solve the end time problem of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, control-theory

The background the ignition delay problem in combustion.

My state vector is $y=[T,Y_i]^T$, $T$ is temperature and $Y_i$ is mass fraction of species.

The evolution of the state vector can be described as an ODEs $\dot y =f(y)$

The quantity of interest is the iginition delay time $\tau$ defined as:
$\ddot T(\tau) = 0$

I do not want to integrate along the time to guess where is the ignition delay. However, I cannot find math term to describe the problem. It is very similar to the minimum time control problem. But there is no control and the ODEs is autonomous.

Definition of ignintion delay looks like this: It is the inflection point of temperature with time.

[image]

Comment: You should not use $y$ as your state vector. In control it is common to use $x$ as your state vector and $y$ as your output vector, you should stick to this convention.

Comment: Sorry for the convention problem. It is because we often use $y$ in chemical reaction kinetics formulation to represent mass fractions. $x$ is used to represent molar fractions.

Answer (score 0):

You have the state equation

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}} =\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x})$$

in which $\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} T &Y_i\end{bmatrix}^T$ and $\boldsymbol{f} = \begin{bmatrix}f_1 & f_2 \end{bmatrix}^T.$

What you are looking for is 
$$\ddot{T}=\dfrac{d}{dt}{\dot{T}}=\dfrac{d}{dt}f_1(\boldsymbol{x})=\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial\boldsymbol{x}}\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}f_1\\f_2 \end{bmatrix}=f_1\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+f_2\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}.$$

Evaluating the last expression at $\tau$ and setting it equal to $0$ will give you a nonlinear equation that you need to solve. Note, that you will also need to know at the same time what your $\boldsymbol{x}(\tau)$ is.

I think you first need to solve the given condition for $\boldsymbol{x}(\tau)$ and then find the $\tau$ that is corresponding to this $\boldsymbol{x}(\tau)$.

Comment: Yes, I can solve the equation you gave to get a condition for $\ddot T = 0$, But how can I get $x(\tau)$ without integration with time? It is an autonomous system.

Comment: Without knowing the exact structure of your system it is difficult to say how you can do it. It might be easy or impossible.

Comment: The ODEs describe a fixed volume of exploding gas. The system is highly nonlinear. It is very difficult to analyze it.